# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'Name' Django error

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

So I am creating an api : and just simply export a certain model into xls. I set up the settings according to the documentation,
[https://www.pythoncircle.com/post/190/how-to-download-data-as-csv-and-excel-file-in-django/#:~:text=Download%20data%20as%20Excel%20file%20in%20Django%3A&text=It%20is%20always%20recommended%20to,command%20to%20add%20xlwt%20package.&text=Inside%20your%20view%2C%20import%20xlwt,create%20and%20download%20excel%20file.but](https://www.pythoncircle.com/post/190/how-to-download-data-as-csv-and-excel-file-in-django/#:%7E:text=Download%20data%20as%20Excel%20file%20in%20Django%3A&text=It%20is%20always%20recommended%20to,command%20to%20add%20xlwt%20package.&text=Inside%20your%20view%2C%20import%20xlwt,create%20and%20download%20excel%20file.but) I got this error when running:

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'Name'

model:

class Task(models.Model):

```
Id=models.IntegerField()
Name=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False,blank=True)
Image1=models.FileField(blank=True, default="",
 upload_to="media/images",null=True)
Image2=models.FileField(blank=True, default="",
 upload_to="media/images",null=True)
Date=models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.Name)
```

#viewset:

class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

```
def list(self, request):
    try:
        response=HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
        response['Content-Disposition']='attachment; filename="users.xls"'

        wb=xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
        ws=wb.add_sheet('Tasks')
        
        row_num=0

        font_style=xlwt.XFStyle()
        font_style.font.bold=True
        columns=['Id','Name','Image1','Image2','Date']
        for col_num in range(len(columns)):
            ws.write(row_num,col_num,columns[col_num],font_style)
        
        font_style=xlwt.XFStyle()
        data=Task.objects.all().values_list('Id','Name','Image1','Image2','Date')
        for  i in data:
            print(i.Name)
        for my_row in data:
            row_num+=1
            
            ws.write(row_num,0,my_row.Id,font_style)
            ws.write(row_num,1,my_row.Name,font_style)
            ws.write(row_num,2,my_row.Image1,font_style)
            ws.write(row_num,3,my_row.Image2,font_style)
            ws.write(row_num,4,my_row.Date,font_style)
        wb.save(response)
        
        return response
        
    except Exception as error:
        traceback.print_exc()
        return Response({"message": str(error), "success": False}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Trac

Answer (score 0):

A `.values_list` returns a `QuerySet` of *tuples*, so in order to access the `Name` field, you do this with:

```
data = Task.objects.values_list('Id', 'Name', 'Image1', 'Image2', 'Date')
for i in data:
    print(i[1])
```

But here there is not that much of a reason to use `.values_list(…)` anyway. You can just fetch the objects with:

```
data = Task.objects.all()
for i in data:
    print(i.Name)
```

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PerlCase*, so it should be: `name` instead of <s>`Name`</s>.

Comment: i tried yuor suggestions,now i am getting,= message": "Unexpected data type <class 'django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile'>

Comment: my code is supposed t download excel sheet,not working

Comment: @AshuoshMishra: I'm afraid that is because the view contains a *lot* of problems. The first one (about the `Name` error is now fixed) :)

Comment: @AshuoshMishra: for example for the `Image`, it should be `ws.write(row_num,2,my_row.Image1.url,font_style)` (same with `Image2`), or something else, but regardless, if it is a `FileField`, you can not add a `File` to an excel sheet...

Comment: Name is working fine,could you please help in this,i need excel shettl,i followed the code as per the documentation of above mentioned site

Comment: but my task is to add image to the excel sheet,

Comment: @AshuoshMishra: then you should take a look at https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_images.html

Comment: ok,i will see that,suppose if there is no image,will mmy code work.can you tell me

Comment: buddy i am getting the excel sheet,but that is very messed up